# Need help solving this set of differential equations of motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm a masters student and I have a set of Differential equations I need to solve for my research. For context they are equations of motion for scalar fields coupled to gravity, though I suppose that's not really relevant to the maths involved.

Specifically, they take the form
$$\chi''(\rho)+2A'(\rho)\chi'(\rho)-(\chi'(\rho))^2-12=0$$
$$A''(\rho)-A'(\rho)\chi'(\rho)+2(A'(\rho))^2-24=0$$
$$2(A'(\rho))^2-2(\chi'(\rho))^2-24=0$$

Now, I already know that there are solutions where $\chi'$ and A' are constant ($\chi'=2$, $A'=4$). However, I know from existing literature using a different number of dimensions that there should also be another solution taking the form of a sum of (natural) logarithms of hyperbolic functions, such that when $\rho\rightarrow\infty$, $\chi$ and A tend to the constant solutions. The problem is that for the life of me I cannot figure out how to find this additional solution. I have tried writing out trial solutions of the form
$$\chi=\chi_0+\chi_1\log(\cosh(\chi_2\rho))+\chi_3\log(\sinh(\chi_4\rho))$$
$$A=A_0+A_1\log(\cosh(A_2\rho))+A_3\log(\sinh(A_4\rho))$$
But despite my best efforts I haven't been able to decipher any kind of solution or determine the constants so far. I feel a little embarrassed because I should probably be able to solve this kind of thing by now but I desperately need some help here. Im not even really sure where to start, apart from redefining $\chi_4$ and $A_4$ in terms of the other constants. I'm using mathematica if that helps at all. Apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: The denizens of math overflow have been known to have better responses to this type of question, but I'm certain some members of this site will also have reasonable insight.  I see that there are some minor evaluations possible with linear combinations of the equations provided, have you already considered insights from these? (I would guess Mathematica would provide some of these already...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\psi,B)=(\chi',A')$; then \begin{gather*}
\psi'+2B\psi-\psi^2=12 \\
B'-B\psi+2B^2=24 \\
B^2-\psi^2=12 \tag{1}
\end{gather*}  We can try to remove some nonlinearities by taking linear combinations.  Adding, $$\psi'+B'+B\psi+2B^2-\psi^2=36$$  Now substituting the hyperbola condition (1): $$\psi'+B'+B(\psi+B)=24$$

But at this point, our equation is secretly 1-D.  Note that $$2B=(B-\psi)+(B+\psi)=\frac{12}{B+\psi}+B+\psi\tag{2}$$  Thus if $u=B+\psi$, then we have the following autonomous ODE: $$24=u'+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{12}{u}+u\right)u=u'+6+\frac{u^2}{2}$$  Canceling, we discover a disguised [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) $$36=2u'+u^2$$

Riccati equations have a trick: let $u=\frac{2v'}{v}$; then $$36=\frac{4(v''v-v'^2)+4v'^2}{v^2}=\frac{4v''}{v}$$  Thus $$v=\alpha\sinh{\sqrt{9}t}+\beta\cosh{\sqrt{9}t}$$

Correspondingly, $$\psi+B=u=\frac{2v'}{v}=6\cdot\frac{\alpha\cosh{3t}+\beta\sinh{3t}}{\alpha\sinh{3t}+\beta\cosh{3t}}$$  Solving for $B$ and $\psi$ via (2) and matching your boundary conditions is something I leave to you.

Comment: You can also combine $w=2B-\psi$, then $w'+w^2=60$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: "Could it be?"  It is!  I think I've corrected the arithmetic now, but it's late at night, so _caveat emptor_.

Comment: I'm also not free of errors in details, it has to be $w'+w^2=2·24-12=36$, so that the square root in the "frequency" also resolves nicely here, $$w=6\frac{\gamma\cosh(6t)+\delta\sinh(6t)}{\gamma\sinh(6t)+\delta\cosh(6t)}.$$

Comment: So integrating once more we get \begin{align}A+\chi&=2\ln(v)+c_1=2\ln(α\sinh(3t)+β\cosh(3t))+c_1,\\2A-\chi&=\ln(...)+c_2=\ln(γ\sinh(6t)+δ\cosh(6t))+c_2.\end{align} This fits nicely into the remembered form of the solution. One needs to check that all 3 given equations are actually satisfied, this might give additional conditions on the constants.

Comment: A very elegant solution!

Comment: Thank you all so much this was immensely helpful, Its clear to see where the form of the solution comes from now.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting eqn. (3) into the first yields that
\begin{align}
\chi''\pm2\chi'\sqrt{(\chi')^2+24}=(\chi')^2+12.
\end{align}
Taking $\chi'=p(\chi)$
\begin{align}
pp'\pm2p\sqrt{p^2+24}=p^2+12,\\
\chi=\int\frac{p\ \mathrm dp}{p^2\mp2p\sqrt{p^2+24}+12}+c_1.
\end{align}
Which, to my surprise, has the elementary solution
\begin{align}
\chi=\frac{1}{12}\Big[\log\left(\left|\frac{2p^3+48p\pm(p^2+12)\sqrt{p^2+24}}{-2p^3-48p\pm(p^2+12)\sqrt{p^2+24}}\right|\right)+4\log\left(\left|\frac{\pm\sqrt{p^2+24}-p}{\pm\sqrt{p^2+24}+p}\right|\right)-\log\left(\left|p^4+24p^2-48\right|\right)\Big]+c_1.
\end{align}

(As computed by <[integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)>), my rudimentary check against a numerically computed integral in Desmos seemed to agree.

Recall from a few lines ago that $p=\chi'$. This resulting equation may make it seem that all hope is lost, but that isn't so. Denote our integral as $F(p)$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\chi=c_1+F(\chi').
\end{align}
The solution to such an equation can be found through the great technique known as 'integration by differentiation' which I first found in *Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations / Andrei D. Polyanin, Valentin F. Zaitsev.--2nd e*.

\begin{align}
\rho=\int\frac{F(s)'}{s}\mathrm ds+c_2,\quad \chi=F(s)+c_1,
\end{align}
perhaps you can derive this yourself? It's a satisfying one. A hint: take a derivative.

This integral has an elementary solution as well! This never happens I swear. Interestingly WolframAlpha does not give a solution. I will spare you the couple lines of equation it yields. Let's denote the solution $G(s)$, so that
\begin{align}
\rho=G(s)+c_2,\quad \chi=F(s)+c_1.
\end{align}

Following the same recipe for  $A$ yields a more complicated yet still elementary integral
\begin{align}
A=\int\frac{q\ \mathrm dq}{-2q^2\mp iq\sqrt{q^2+24}+24}+k_1\equiv\tilde F(q)+k_1,\quad [q=A'],
\end{align}
with the implicit solution
\begin{align}
\rho=\tilde G(t)+k_2, \quad A=\tilde F(t)+k_1,
\end{align}
where $\tilde G(t)=\smallint (\tilde F(t)'/t)\mathrm dt$.

The solution for $A(\rho)$ is similar to that for $\chi(\rho)$, just a bit longer. I believe Mathematica would be useful for the integrals.  Let me know if there are any errors.